# "Invalid column index" SqlException error when trying to insert a row

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm having a problem with setting up a `PreparedStatement` to insert a new row into my table. I've tested the query in my SQL editor and it worked succesfully but I can't get this PreparedStatement to work.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table game(gamedate, type, world) values (TIMESTAMP '?', ?, '?');"
runQuery(sql, date, type, world);
```

...

```
protected runQuery(String sql, Object... params){
try {
  initiateConnection();
  PreparedStatement statement = connection.PrepareStatement(sql);

    int i = 1;
    for (Object p : params){
       statement.setObject(i, p);
       i++;
     }
   statement.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception ex){

} finally {
 //close up things
}
}
```

I added in some println() to test the output and it seemed to all be pretty okay

```
sql: INSERT INTO game(gamedate, type, world) values(TIMESTAMP '?', ?, '?');
date: 2012-03-13 21:42:14
type: 1
world: test
```

The error I get is

> java.sql.SQLException invalid column index

I'm really quite stumped here. Any idea what's the culprit here?

Comment: why no single quote for 2nd "?"

Comment: First column looks something wrong.. Is that valid?

Comment: When I try an example query in my SQL editor it works fine. 

ex:
INSERT INTO game(gamedate, type, world) values(TIMESTAMP '2012-01-01 14:00:00', 1, 'test')

compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two guesses:

- you don't need quotes around the question marks. Get rid of those
- the `TIMESTAMP` function might be problematic. Try converting the date to a timestamp before setting it in the prepared statement. (`date.getTime() / 1000`)

Comment: I got rid of the quotes, but I don't understand your second suggestion. How does dividing it by 1000 get me a timestamp? Won't that cause a conflict trying to insert a number in a table expecting a timestamp?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind. I Figured it out. Thank you, the Timestamp function was indeed causing some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement has only one substitutable placeholder. The ones in single quotes are literal question marks.